# How to record sound playing in headset using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, recording

I'm trying to record screen and input/output audio on a headset but its recording only audio from headset microphone. How can I record the sound I'm hearing through headset

```
ffmpeg -y  -f gdigrab -framerate ntsc -i desktop  -f dshow -i audio="Headset Microphone (Plantronics C320-M)" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast "video output.mp4"
```

Comment: You've set your input to your headset. You need another input for your computer audio.

Comment: I tried setting audio="Stereo Mix (Conexant ISST Audio)" its recording computer audio only when headset is disconnected. But when I connect USB headset its not recording. I see these three devices in the list of audio devices `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`  
Headset Microphone (Plantronics C320-M), 
Stereo Mix (Conexant ISST Audio), 
Internal Microphone (Conexant ISST Audio)

Comment: my headset microphone is listed in devices, but not "earphone" output. I ended up recording with OBS.